# How to change a custom policy to be able to log in with a custom attribute (National Identity Document)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Currently I only find documentation that allows me to change my email / username / phone number, but nothing talks about adding a user attribute as an authentication entity for the login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the new identifier to `signInNames.whatever`, exactly like the “change identifier” samples work. They just overwrite an existing value, if one didn’t exist, it just gets created automatically.

You can’t add an identifier to /any/ attribute, it has to go into `signInNames` attribute, as that is uniquely constrained.

Comment: Apparently it only works for the signUp, but in reality I need to authenticate by the document number

Comment: You need to write the doc number into signInNames.docNumber. At sign-in, you don’t need to make any changes other than switching the operating mode of the sign in technical profile to username and using the appropriate regex restriction for the signInName field. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata

Comment: thank you!!!!!!! I needed to ensure that it could not be done otherwise

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT When you create something like `signInNames.whatever` are you limited to 64 characters in length (like with username)? I am hoping for a way to get ~300 chars.

Comment: No, the limit is much higher if you use .foo. Around 500char.